# Vuetify table gives an error on loading data

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

The following code gives an error 'Property "item" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance'. But when i change the  to just a normal  everything works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.5.3/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.4.19/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.5.3/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
    
    <div id="app">
          <v-table>
            <tbody>
              <tr v-for="item in routes">
                <td>{{item.customerName}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </v-table>
    </div>

    <script>
      const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
      const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
      const vuetify = createVuetify()

      const app = createApp({
        data: () => ({
          routes: [{"id":1,"customerName":"Pietje puk", "orderNumber":"PF-123456789", "zipcode":"5388AA,18"},
                   {"id":2,"customerName":"van de Graaf", "orderNumber":"TEST", "zipcode":"1234AA"}]
        }),
        setup() {
          const date = ref();
        }
      });

      app.use(vuetify).mount('#app')
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried almost everything, but nothing seems to work. Tried different versions as well. It looks like this component has an issue, but i am new to Vuetify so maybe there is another thing wrong in my code? Our AI friend could not help me out here ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `v-table` from Vuetify version 2, but you are importing version 3.

```
<v-table>
    <template #default>
        <tbody>
            <tr
                v-for="item in routes"
                :key="item.id"
            >
                <td>{{ item.customerName }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.orderNumber }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.zipcode }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </template>
</v-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that Vue 3 uses a different template syntax than Vue 2, and some features are not supported in simple HTML files.

1. use a bundler tool such as Webpack or Rollup to transpile your code to a compatible formats.

   [online example](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

2.like @Sambal said, you can add a <template #default> to achieve it.

```
<v-table>
    <template #default>
        <tbody>
            <tr
                v-for="item in routes"
                :key="item.id"
            >
                <td>{{ item.customerName }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.orderNumber }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.zipcode }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </template>
</v-table>
```